# AFNetworking API call status code

Tags: ios, api, response, afnetworking

Is there a possibility that `AFNetworking` takes `API` status code in consideration as well?

Call returns 200 HTTP code that it is ok, but status code is 406 which indicates failure.

[image: Screenshot]

This results to `AFNetworking` success block being called, even though API call failed.
Is there a solution to this?

Code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

NSString *APICallURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", SERVER_URL, @"something.php"];

[manager GET:APICallURL parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    if (success) {
        success();
    }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    if (failure) {
        failure(error);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

`X-API-Status-Code` is a totally non-standard header (as any header starting with `X-...` actually, by definition).

That header is a proprietary way that your specific server chose to report the API status code. It could have picked any other proprietary header to do so, maybe calling it `X-API-ReturnCode`or whatnot.

So I doubt that `AFNetworking` will ever support this natively.

---

**But** you can probably [create your own `AFURLResponseSerialization` subclass and implement `validateResponse`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFURLResponseSerialization.h#L94), so that your code check for this proprietary header and act accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It will not reach failure block for any failure status code from server. With respect to AFNetworking, network call is successful with a error code from server.

It will reach failure block only when we are not able to successfully finish the network call, like 
       1) Time out error
       2) Server down and not able to reach
       3) Network loss etc

Solution is we should check the status code of network call in success block and identify error responses from server